# Printing specific array positions in Java (Console)

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, printing, console

I have an array in Java (console based) and I would like to print out the details stored in one of the positions when the user enters it. For example, they enter "3" into the console application and then the program responds with the details matching the request.

Thanks in advance!

```
if(input.matches("S")){
// If user input matches with S, then the user willSSN be asked to enter a array position and then the corresponding information will be shown



    KeyStroke[] patientsDetails = new KeyStroke[5];
    patientsDetails[0] = new KeyStroke(9,"OX5BJM","Peter",2039489);
    patientsDetails[1] = new KeyStroke(12,"OX1BOL","Kim",2434587);
    patientsDetails[2] = new KeyStroke(67,"OX2VBN","Patrick",2233842);
    patientsDetails[3] = new KeyStroke(34,"OX2XHB","Liam",2432340);
    patientsDetails[4] = new KeyStroke(54,"OX3BUN","Bob",2234098);

    System.out.println("Enter an array postion from 0 to 4 to show paitients corresponding postion and details");

    number1 = enterNumber0.nextInt();
     if (input.matches("0")){

        System.out.println(patientsDetails[0]);
    }
```

Comment: It is a part of a program. Not sure what the problem with asking a question specific to my work is?

Comment: its a very basic question which indicates no effort of studying or researching

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is situated after you print `"Enter an array position from 0 to 4..."` to the console.

Try and replace

```
number1 = enterNumber0.nextInt();
     if (input.matches("0")){

        System.out.println(patientsDetails[0]);
    }
```

with

```
number1 = enterNumber0.nextInt(); // is enterNumber0 the name of your Scanner object?
System.out.println(patientsDetails[number1]); // I assume that number1 is declared as an `int` somewhere in your code?
```

If I didn't get the full picture of your problem, please excuse me and try to clarify the problem a bit better.

Comment: Hi! That is very helpful, but when I run the program it prints something that I'm unable to make any sense of.

Comment: "Enter an array postion from 0 to 4 to show paitients corresponding postion and details" After this I enter "0" and it gives me this: 
client.KeyStroke@3e99f610

Comment: That's probably the Object's hashcode you are seeing. Does it look something like `code.KeyStroke@2f92e0f4`? If so, you will have to override the `.toString()` method of the KeyStroke class or make your own method that will allow you to show the various patients details.